# Load a class for reflection when it's already loaded from elsewhere in java

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I'm trying to write a decompiler for Java using reflection (all I need is the method signature information from a jar file passed in).  I'm using a `URLClassLoader` to load classes from the jar file, and then pass that class on to my decompiler.

However, I've run into a problem.  The jar I'm trying to read contains different versions of classes already loaded into my environment.  So when I call

```
ClassLoader myClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(jars, null);
Class<?> classToDecompile = Class.forName(className, false, myClassLoader);
```

It returns not the class from my jar file, but the one that's already been loaded.  Is there a way to load the class information for reflection only and get it from the jar passed in rather than from the JRE?

**Edit:**

The jar I'm trying to decompile contains classes in the java.lang package, which causes a security exception to be thrown:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang

Comment: Well, it turns out I don't care too much about the java.* stuff being different than my current JRE, so I can just filter that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) - which URLClassLoader inherits - first checks for a previously-loaded class, and then, not finding any, checks with the parent class loader. You could override that method to bypass the check for a previously-loaded class. Not sure if you'd have to bypass the parent.

Mind you, this would be an evil class loader; you probably shouldn't use it for anything else.

You might also try reading the jar yourself, getting the contents of the class file (the byte codes), and calling ClassLoader.defineClass(name, byte[], int, int) yourself, supplying a unique name for the class. I think that's a better idea, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Why wasting time when there is [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad)? If you still want to achieve that you have to write your own class loader with [child-first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5445511/696632) strategy.