# Java or Scala plugin framework

Tags: java, plugins, osgi, classloader

I am developing a framework where jars can be dropped into a folder and scanned for a function that can be called later. My first implementation used naive ClassLoader method where the jars were loaded and the class instance created. This is plugin architecture.
The problem I ran into is the versioning. Let's say for example my host app is using third-party lib that depends on org.joda time version 1.6 and the plugin is dependent on version 2.1 of the same (newer ) library. 
I tried to use the [Java Simple Plugin Framework](http://code.google.com/p/jspf/) but it does not seem to load my plug-ins using custom class loaders (which is what i assume i will need to overcome the version conflict and have the 2.1 version actually loaded). 
My next step is to try osgi. 
So, the question is: is this the right approach or is there a simple way that i don't know, I am coming from .net world and don't know java too well but i remember dll hell, and this seems to be the java version of it. I am developing in Scala btw, but that should not matter to the main question.

Comment: Have you looked at maven?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals what do you mean? yes, i am using maven to build jars

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question. I have not used maven personally, but I understand that a use of maven is to resolve dependency requirements/conflicts.

Comment: Yes maven has a repository where the jar versions declare their dependencies on other jars' version. OSGi manages versions too; specifically using several version at the same time. If you on the other hand need a sledge hammer to hot swap class chenges, look at JRebel.

Comment: maybe i was not clear in my question, this is a run-time plugin architecture, so when my host runs, it should use the version 1.6 of the library, but when it calls the plug-in, the 2.1 should be used correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar use-case. I wanted a simple plugin framework much like you have described, but was not ready to jump into OSGi. I went the custom classloader route, but ran into much the same problems as you have. I did try a [Parent-Last Classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445511/how-do-i-create-a-parent-last-child-first-classloader-in-java-or-how-to-overr), which did help with some of the jar conflicts. That might be something to look into. I looked fairly seriously into what the CI Server [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) had done for their plugin system - and found [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/RkDu1teCiHo/nWMseSn2Iz8J) interesting.

In the end, I needed to be able to track when services are coming and going, have a service registry, etc... and realized that I was re-inventing OSGi. I switched over to pure OSGi, and even though there is a learning curve and it can be a pain sometimes, I'm glad I did.

Comment: sounds like you have a much more complicated system than what i need, and i am not ready to jump into osgi. thanks for the jenkins hint.

Answer (score 3):

Try [ScalaScriptEngine](https://github.com/kostaskougios/scalascriptengine/tree/master). It allows you to dynamically load and compile classes from source files and supports quite a few advanced features.